# save web Images with Xperia Z1

Tags: browser, images

How can I save web Images with xperia z1 ? (kitkat)
I search for and image in google and find it. now how can I save it. it doen't have save image option like old versions :(

Comment: Yeah this has been annoying me for a while. I **think** they removed it as there was potential copyright issues, for example 500 px has scripts that stop you saving images by long pressing them as normal. The only options I know of are either taking a screenshot in the search app (not great) or clicking on the link, going to the website in a browser and saving the image from there (also not great).